# Выдает ошибку Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

Делаю парсер цен и другой инфы с сайта.
Вот ссылка на всю эту инфу: https://loot.farm/fullprice.json

Вот мой код:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(300);

$urljson = file_get_contents("http://loot.farm/fullprice.json");
$data = json_decode($urljson)->price;

echo $data;
?>
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема? Я уже делал парсер для другого сайта, там все было понятнее. Видно раз массив, 2 массив и т.д.

Comment: Масcив и Объект - это разные вещи, до того как вставить в json_decode вы хоть пробовали проверить какие данные идут к вам ? var_dump($urljson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `json_decode($urljson)` - не объект, а массив. Надо вот так:

```
$data = json_decode($urljson);
foreach($data as $obj) {
    echo $obj->price.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит убрать обращение к свойству price из первой строчки..

Comment: А зачем foreach и $obj?

Comment: @vp_arth, поторопился и перепутал... и не только в этом месте. сейчас норм должно быть.

Comment: @6o6ep, исправил - последний вариант посмотрите. foreach - потому что Вы получаете не один объект со свойствами, а целый массив объектов со свойствами.

Comment: СПС. Сейчас работает. Я просто прошлый раз на чистом копипесте сделал. А сейчас хоть разобрался

Comment: @Александр Белинский, а как сделать что бы я мог определенный элемент вызвать? Тоесть не все сразу, а только первый или второй? И вызывать не только цену, но и название